# How to Process in DataWindow in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am populating a DataWindow with some data. Some of the column names are "Request No", "Status", etc.

"Status" column can contain values like "Pending", "Active","Expired".

Whenever the DataWindow is populated I want to count the number of records in PowerBuilder which are having status as "Active".

After getting the count of the records I will be populating the count in some static text.

Can anybody help me , how to achieve this, as I am new to PowerBuilder.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you your answer, but it introduces you to what we PowerBuilder developers know as "Tilde Hell".

```
ll_Count = Long (dw.Describe ("Evaluate('sum (if((status = ~~~"Active~~~"),1,0))',1)"))
```

The tilde-craziness has to do with what each level of string evaluation boils the expression down to for the next evaluation. (~~ boils down to ~, and ~" boils down to " which is useful if your string is enclosed in double quotes)

`Evaluate(<expression>, <row>)` inside a `Describe()` will return the value for `<expression>` on a given row. (Since `<row>` is irrelevant to a `sum()` operation which works across the full data set, all you need to do is make sure it's a valid row, i.e. in this example, that there is at least one row.)

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Couldn't he also put that expression -- sum (if((status = "Active"),1,0)) -- into a hidden computed field on his datawindow and then evaluate that hidden field? Might could down on the tildes.

Comment: My first reaction was no, because it would evaluate more often than you want (e.g. every time you scrolled), making it inefficient. Besides, if you want to do PowerBuilder, you need to learn to love the tilde. But, now my reaction is no, because it shouldn't be hidden; it should be in the footer replacing the statictext display. I like this solution even better.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to filter the DW data by using your criteria, then to get the rows count.

Something like:

```
dw_ctrl.SetFilter("status='Active'")
dw_ctrl.Filter()
ll_count = dw_ctrl.RowCount()
//...
//don't forget to reset filter after that
dw_ctrl.SetFilter("")
dw_ctrl.Filter()
```

Comment: This solution works also I'd probably use the computed field mentioned by Slapout. If you used this one it might be good to SetRedraw(false) first and then SetRedraw(true) after on your datawindow control to avoid any flickering.